Did Einstein himself ever follow up on his theory that light travels with infinite velocity?
In reading the freely available English translation of "On the electrodynamics of moving bodies" I find on page 10 Einstein himself conducts a critical evaluation of the domain of validity of his earlier derived Lorentz factor and then says,

"we shall, however, find in what follows, that the velocity of light in our theory plays the part, physically, of an infinitely great velocity."

I would like some help in finding works by Einstein himself (or peer reviewed works by others) that describe "what follows" in more detail.

Not sure I would trust that translation, but even if that translation is correct, he certainly did "follow up" on that: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity

I think the translation is trying to mean that, in the following part of that paper and that paper alone, the $c\to\infty$ limit is taken and shown to reduce back to Galilean relativity. Something akin to that, or maybe it is talking about momentum or energy instead (which would be even more physically insightful).

I think Einstein is simply stating that c is the limiting velocity. But I read On the Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies several decades ago (in English, on paper).

You're asking whether Einstein did any further work on relativity after 1905?

Einstein did not know the velocity of light as it was not discovered then. That's why he said with its apparently infinitely large velocity. Another reason why he considered it to be the ultimate speed!

@Ritzthephysibeast Long before Einstein, the speed of light was known to be finite:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light#History

The full quote implies Einstein knew the speed of light was finite:  "For velocities greater than that of light our deliberations become meaningless; we shall, however, find in what follows, that the velocity of light in our theory plays the part, physically, of an infinitely great velocity."  (I would interpret "physically infinitely great" to mean "physically unreachable".)

rapidity

He didn't have a theory that light travels with infinite velocity. The speed of light was known to be finite (and its value was known to a precision of several digits) in 1905.
What he meant by that passage is that the role of the speed $c$ in special relativity is similar in some ways to infinite speed in Newtonian physics. You can't reach it by accelerating, and in fact no matter how much you accelerate, the difference between your speed and $c$ never gets any smaller (it's always $c$). That's reflected in the formula for the composition of velocities that he derives in the next section. I think that section is what he meant by "what follows".

I went back to the original german text.
All of Einstein's writings are made available by the Einstein Papers project. In Volume 2: Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter Körper
However, for this purpose a more convenient source is the set made available by profesor Ulrich Eckern of the papers published by Einstein in 'Annalen der Physik'.
PDF file with scans: Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter Körper

The sentence of the question in the original german:

Für Überlichtgeschwindigkeiten werden unsere Überlegungen sinnlos; wir werden übrigens in den folgenden Betrachtungen finden, daß die Lightgeschwindigkeit in unserer Theorie physikalisch die Rolle der unendlich großen Geschwindigkeiten spielt.

I translate that as:

For velocities greater than that of light our considerations become meaningless; incidentally, we shall find in the following examinations that the velocity of light in our theory plays the part, physically, of an infinitely great velocity.

In the translation that is used in the question the word 'however' is used. But the word however has a connotation of contrast, and in the original text such contrast is not there. Generally the word 'übrigens' is used to signal to the reader: this is rather a casual remark.
As pointed out by contributor benrg: 'following examinations' refers to the discussion in the next section of the paper.
